# how to center my window in oracle forms 10g

Tags: oracleforms

How to center my window in oracle forms 10g?

Here is my code which isn't working:

```
set_window_property(forms_mdi_window, window_state, maximize);

set_window_property('window1',x_pos,(get_window_property(forms_mdi_window,width)-get_window_property('window1',width))/2);

set_window_property('window1',y_pos,(get_window_property(forms_mdi_window,height)-get_window_property('window1',height))/2);
```

Do you have any idea, why? Thanks.

Comment: It's such a nice question for versions Forms10+, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set_window_property(forms_mdi_window, window_state, maximize);

set_window_property('PURCHASE',x_pos,(get_window_property(forms_mdi_window,width)-get_window_property('PURCHASE',width)-10)/2);
set_window_property('PURCHASE',y_pos,(get_window_property(forms_mdi_window,height)-get_window_property('PURCHASE',height))/2);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65718266/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 4):

Don't set it to maximize to begin, then you can't change the dimensions anymore. Then afterwards I use this code:

```
declare
     mdiwidth number;
     mdiheight number;
     winid window;
     v_window VARCHAR2(50) := get_view_property(get_item_property( name_in( 'SYSTEM.CURSOR_ITEM' ), ITEM_CANVAS), WINDOW_NAME );
 begin
    winid := find_window(v_window);
    mdiwidth := get_window_property(FORMS_MDI_WINDOW, width);
    mdiheight := get_window_property(FORMS_MDI_WINDOW, height);
    set_window_property(winid, position, 
                        greatest(mdiwidth/2 - get_window_property(winid, width)/2 - 2, 0),
                        greatest(mdiheight/2 - get_window_property(winid, height)/2 - 40, 0));
end;
```

The adjustment of 40 in height is for the taksbar.

Comment: Wonderful solution, I'm trying to find such a solution for this question since yesterday,congratulations nigthfox.

Comment: I found that solution and the trigger is when_windows_activated